# NullPointerException: element cannot be mapped to a null key

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I have read the topic:

[Collectors.groupingBy doesn't accept null keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625065/collectors-groupingby-doesnt-accept-null-keys)

But I don't understand how can I apply it for my issue:

my code:

```
Map<String, List<MappingEntry>> mappingEntryMap = mapping.getMappingEntries()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MappingEntry::getMilestone, Collectors.mapping(e -> e, Collectors.toList())));
```

For me `MappingEntry::getMilestone` sometimes can return null. It is ok for my situation but I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: element cannot be mapped to a null key
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$45(Collectors.java:907)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: how about filtering the nulls first?

Comment: @Eugene it is not allowable for my case. I must not lose the data. This approach described in the linked topic

Comment: @gstackoverflow what about applying a default key for all `null` keys?

Comment: Use the oldschool way instead of streams?

Comment: Also `Collectors.mapping(e -> e, Collectors.toList())` can be simplified to `Collectors.toList()`

Comment: @Lino, it is correct

Comment: @Marvin, I undetstand, that I can, but i prefere to use streams. And it looks like stream should have this option

Comment: @Lino … and `Collectors.toList()` can be omitted when using `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Comment: Please checking my answer, solution using Optional instead of raw nulls

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `Collectors.toMap` instead and specify that a `HashMap` is used (as it allows one null key)

```
 Collectors.toMap(
       MappingEntry::getMilestone,
       x -> {
           List<MappingEntry> list = new ArrayList<>();
           list.add(x);
           return list;
       },
       (left, right) -> {
            left.addAll(right);
            return left;
       },
       HashMap::new

)
```

Comment: Not a beautiful solution. You changed the data structure as well as the logic. Doesn't deserve to be the best answer.

Comment: @RajeshPaul there are al least 17 people that disagree with you.

Comment: @RajeshPaul The data structure is still `Map<String, List<MappingEntry>>` and the logic is the same.

Answer (score 17):

Given that you want to retain the `MappingEntry` objects regardless of when `getMilestone()` is *null* or *non-null* and knowing that a `NullPointerException` will be thrown when a particular contract in not met then we can avoid that by using a replacement key to group the `MappingEntry` objects which have a *null* milestone and yet group the other `MappingEntry` objects as they're supposed to be.

```
Map<String, List<MappingEntry>> mappingEntryMap = 
             mapping.getMappingEntries()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(groupingBy(m -> m.getMilestone() == null ?
                                  "absentMilestone" : m.getMilestone()));
```

The trick here is to use a ternary operator which provides a key to group all the `MappingEntry` objects that have a *absent* milestone into a single group and if the milestone is not absent then we can group by its value as you'd expect.

Comment: This is absolutely correct answer and deserves to be chosen as the best answer. Thanks @Ousmane D.

Comment: @RajeshPaul This is absolutely not a correct answer. It changes the behavior of the original code in case `getMilestone()` returns `"absentMilestone"` -- in that case, both the objects for which `"absentMilestone"` is returned by `getMilestone()` and the ones for which `getMilestone()` returns null will end up in the same bucket.

Answer (score 2):

**In my opinion the best solution:**

Use Optional.empty() instead of pasing null value.

```
Map<Optional<String>, List<MappingEntry>> mappingEntryMap = mapping.getMappingEntries()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Optional::ofNullable, Collectors.mapping(e -> e, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Ugh... What's the point of using `HashMap`, which supports null keys, if we still have to use `Optional<X>` keys because the stupid `groupingBy` throws NPE if classifier returns null? That check may as well have been omitted, it would have made everything easier with no loss of safety (NPE would still be thrown upon putting the null key in the map, _if and only if_ the map doesn't support null keys). But unfortunately, this seems to be the best solution, followed by promptly converting the `Map<Optional<X>>` into a `Map<X>` with null keys.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `Stream.collect()`:

```
mapping.getMappingEntries().stream()
  .collect(
    HashMap::new,
    (m,v) -> m.computeIfAbsent(v.getMilestone, tmp -> new ArrayList<>()).add(v),
    (m1, m2) -> {}
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Optional for that:

```
var mappingEntryMap = mapping.getMappingEntries().stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(entry -> ofNullable(entry.getMilestone());
```

And then:

```
var emptyMilestoneList = mappingEntryMap.get(Optional.empty());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Collector.of` method for this to specify a custom collector and use a `HashMap` for the resulting map because according to the `Java-8` docs of `HashMap`

> [...] permits null values and the null key. [...]

```
Collector.of(
    HashMap::new, 
    (map, e) -> map.computeIfAbsent(e.getMileStone(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(e), 
    (left, right) -> {
         right.forEach((key,list) -> left.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).addAll(list));
         return left;
     })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use filter and get only not null data.

like

```
            Map<String, List<Entity>> map = list
                .stream()
                .filter(entity -> entity.getZoneRefId()!=null)
                .collect(
                        Collectors.
                                groupingBy(
                                        Entity::getZoneName));
```