# Structuring List data using Java 8 and normalizing it into a map structure

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

So, I am still new to Java 8 and still struggling to correlate the streams API with traditional iteration and collections.

So I have a List of object "UserData" which has 3 properties, the list is all denormalized data.

```
 public class UserData {

        private String primaryAccountNumber;
        private String subAccountNumber;
        private String currency;
}
```

Sample Input Data would be like

```
PrimaryAccNumber     SubAccNumber   Currency
PA00                 US00           USD
PA01                 US01           USD
PA01                 US02           USD
PA02                 EU00           EUR
PA03                 EU01           EUR
PA04                 CA00           CAD
PA04                 CA01           CAD
null                 IN00           INR
null                 IN01           INR
```

The expected output should be something like

```
USD  -> PA00 -> [US00]
        PA01 -> [US01,US02]
EUR  -> PA02 -> [EU00]
     -> PA03 -> [EU01]
CAD  -> PA04 -> [CA00,CA01]
INR  -> null (or dummykey)->[IN00,IN01]
```

So, i want it to be normalized in a way such that the out come is a Map keyed with currency and the value should be another Map keyed with primary Acc and value with List of sub Accounts.

```
Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>> normalizedData = //logic
```

I was thinking of doing this oldschool way basically

1. Sort the data based on currency.
2. Iterate the list and put the data in Map ( since the data is sorted
   and till i get the duplicate keys will start putting the
   corresponding data ( primary account in a new Map)
3. Repeat the above process basically at primary account level and start putting the duplicate key corresponding 
   value data (sub accounts  in a list object)

As for my thought process i have to create 2 list copies (1 sort at Currency for first iteration) , 2 nd sort at Primary account for nested map. It seems little inefficient, then i looked at the streams but could not visualize how i can use them but any guidance or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward with streams. You need a couple of nested groupings and a mapping at the end. For the sake of brevity, I'll assume you have a static import of `java.util.stream.Collectors.*`.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> normalizedData = users.stream().collect(
        groupingBy(UserData::getCurrency,
                groupingBy(UserData::getPrimaryAccountNumber,
                        mapping(UserData::getSubAccountNumber, toList()))));
```

Note that [`groupingBy()` doesn't allow null keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22625065/1553851), so you may indeed have to use a dummy key.

Comment: Thankyou this is perfect, i am still studying grouping by function and yes in the Account getter i have put the condition to generate a dummy key.